# Queue/database for event scheduling?

Tags: events, nosql, redis, scheduling, priority-queue

I will probably build my own at some point, but in the meantime; is there a language-generic event scheduler—taking e.g.: `{time, priority, action}` as input—that is distributable across shards, and supports:

- enqueue (push) in O(1)
- dequeue (pop) in O(log n)
- next scheduled (find-min) in O(1)
- arbitrary delete in O(log n), e.g.: by using a second priority queue designated `delete_queue`

Was looking at Redis, but couldn't find a proper priority queue interface for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can implement such a queue with Redis with the exact complexity assumption you describe for each operation.

What you can do with Redis is using a zset. Internally, a zset is implemented as a standard hash table plus a skip list (sorted by the score and value). So you can use the score to store timestamps, and the value to encode both priority and action. The order in the zset is the score first, and then the value itself (lexicographically compared). So the idea is to choose a value representation whose lexicographic order corresponds to the logical order you need for the priority. Here I assume that time takes precedence over priority (i.e. priority is only used to order items when they have the same timestamp).

For instance:

```
# timestamp=0, priority=3
zadd myqueue 0 03-action1

# timestamp=10, priority=2
zadd myqueue 10 02-action3

# timestamp=10, priority=1
zadd myqueue 10 01-action2

# The dequeuing order will be action1,action2,action3
# (because of priorities)
```

I believe the complexity of the various operations will be:

- enqueue O(log n) [using zadd]
- dequeue O(log n) [using zremrangebyrank]
- next scheduled item O(1) [using zrange to fetch the first item]
- arbitrary delete O(log n) [using zrem]

They are different of what you are looking for, but they are not so bad.